# Python 2.7 calculating remainder with division and two inputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, modulus

It's a question for my assignment in intro to programming and I'm not quite understanding how to do this without the use of Ifs because our prof just wants basic modulus and division.  Im trying to get 3 outputs.  balloons greater than children (which works), balloons equal to children which just outputs 0 and 0. and balloons less than children, which doesnt work.

```
# number of balloons
children = int(input("Enter number of balloons: "))

# number of children coming to the party
balloons = int(input("Enter the number of children coming to the party: "))

# number of balloons each child will receive
receive_balloons = int(balloons % children)

# number of balloons leftover for decorations
remaining = children % balloons

print("{:s}""{:d}""{:s}""{:d}".format("Number of balloons  for each child is ", receive_balloons, " and the amount leftover is ", remaining))

print(balloons, "", (remaining))
```

Comment: What do you think `%` does? Neither of your uses of it are correct.

Comment: Does it not divide it and calculate the remainder?

Comment: It does, so your problem is probably with the math. Why do you think the *remainder* when dividing the number of balloons by the number of children would be the number of balloons each child receives? Why would you divide the number of *children* by the number of *balloons* and take the remainder to find the number of leftover balloons?

Comment: You are naming your variables incorrectly (`children = number of balloons`). `%` returns just the remained, e.g. `10%8 = 2`, `8%10 = 8`. If you want the division and remainder then you can make 2 calls: `10%8 = 2` and `10//8 = 1`... or you can use the builtin `divmod`, `d, r = divmod(10, 8) [d=1, r=2]`

Comment: When I first wrote it, I had balloons / children.  But it constantly equally 0 on the output even for something like 10/5.  Im not allowed to import any libraries.  Im still just a beginner so this is as far as I got.  I just put the modulus sign as it worked with a few balloon > children inputs.  Also, we aren't allowed anything outside of basics such as you listed "divmod".

Comment: When you enter 10 balloons it is being assigned to the `children` variable...

Comment: Ahhh I see I didnt notice that part

Comment: `divmod` is a python builtin in, like `print`, `input`, etc.

Comment: Side-note: For a pair of `int` operands, `%` is guaranteed to return a Python `int` (or on Py2, possibly `long`, though they're 99.9% interoperable), so `x = int(y % z)` is largely a wasteful no-op when you could just do `x = y % z`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your variable assignment, you are assigning to the wrong variables and actually divide the numbers to get `receive_balloons` correctly:

```
balloons = int(input("Enter number of balloons: "))
children = int(input("Enter the number of children coming to the party: "))

receive_balloons = balloons // children
remaining = balloons % children

# Alternatively
receive_balloons, remaining = divmod(balloons, children)

print("Number of balloons for each child is {} and the amount leftover is {}".format(receive_balloons, remaining))
```

Output (10/5):

```
Enter number of balloons: 10
Enter the number of children coming to the party: 5
Number of balloons for each child is 2 and the amount leftover is 0
```

Output (10/8):

```
Enter number of balloons: 10
Enter the number of children coming to the party: 8
Number of balloons for each child is 1 and the amount leftover is 2
```

Note: in Python2.7 you should use `raw_input`.

Comment: So i've switched around the variables to be in correct order and now the recieve balloons only outputs 0 which is what I had previouslyEnter number of children: 10
Enter the number of balloons: 5
Number of balloons  for each child is 0 and the amount leftover is 5

Comment: Sorry not able to replicate your issue... see output above.

Comment: If i utilize raw_input I get an undefined variable

Comment: Perhaps you are not using python 2.7.

Comment: Alright thank you very much for the help! I will double check my version.

Comment: @AChampion: That seems likely, otherwise the output for `print(balloons, "", (remaining))` would be a weird looking `tuple` that would probably bother them.

Comment: Sorry the last part of the code was just random jabber I just wanted to see the numbers for those variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the // operator for the number of balloons per child and % for remaining balloons

```
# number of balloons
balloons = int(input("Enter number of balloons: "))

# number of children coming to the party
children = int(input("Enter the number of children coming to the party: "))

receive_balloons, remaining = (balloons // children, balloons % children)

print("{:s}""{:d}""{:s}""{:d}".format("Number of balloons  for each child is ", receive_balloons, " and the amount leftover is ", remaining))

print(balloons, "", (remaining))
```

Comment: This works but if it's possible for my knowledge can you explain the 

receive_balloons, remaining = (balloons // children, balloons % children)?
I didn't know you could do a double calculation

Comment: You can unpack a `tuple` in assignment, e.g. `a, b = (1, 2)` is the same `a=1` and `b=2`, the above code creates a `tuple` of the values from division and modulus and assigns them to the variables. Syntactic sugar.

Comment: In the example the assignment is also unpacking a tuple. The tuple being the bit in the brackets. Each element of the tuple is individually assigned to a variable.

Comment: @roysizzle: And note, the parens aren't necessary; the commas themselves cause implicit `tuple` construction on the right side, and sequence unpacking on the left side, so `receive_balloons, remaining = balloons // children, balloons % children` works fine. Or since you're doing both operations anyway, it might be worth using `divmod` for simplicity, reduced repetition: `receive_balloons, remaining = divmod(balloons, children)`

Comment: divmod is my preferred method as well. Question says just division and modulus

Comment: I'm sure we will learn about divmod but as of right now I don't believe I'm allowed to use this function since we have not learned it yet.